# how to get UIPopoverController from UIWebView

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I load a webpage in a `uiwebviewcontroller`，after click one link, it will pop a `popovercontroller`, is it possible to get this controller in my code?

Actually, this `popovercontroller` is not created by my code. The html detect the webpage is loaded by `iDevice` and pop this. That means, if I use safari to open webpage, it also will display this `popovercontroller`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement the UIWebView delegate method.

```
  -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
   {
       NSURL *url = request.URL;
       NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
       if([urlString isEqualToString :@"abc.com") // link on which want to open popoverview 
       {
           UIPopoverController  itemPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
          [itemPopover presentPopoverFromRect:customCell.addImage.bounds inView:webViewpermittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

            return NO; //if wanted to load the link on UIWebview return YES else return NO
       }



        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this popovercontroller is not created by my code. The html detect the webpage is loaded by iDevice and pop this. That means, if I use safari to open webpage, it also will display this popovercontroller